# Python - Searching for a value in CSV column and return string

Tags: python, windows

I am very new to Python and am working on a simple project that part of which is supposed to search for a user defined variable, and if found, return a string based on the row it was found.

I've read many posts that lead me to the code that I have, but when ran, while I don't get an error, the code continues onto the next part. In this case I omitted the following parts, but if run by itself, breaks after the input variable.

```
import csv #CSV File Handling

#Define variables for customer file reading and appending
custData = open('custData.csv', 'a+')
custFields = ['ContactLast','ContactFirst','Company','Credit','Phone','Address','City','State','Zip']
reader = csv.DictReader(custData, delimiter=',')
writer = csv.DictWriter(custData, fieldnames=custFields)
search = ''

#Open the file
with custData:

#Display the Welcome Message and Main Menu
    mainmenugo = 'Y'
    while (mainmenugo.upper() == 'Y'):

        print ('-------------------- What would you like to do? ------------------\n'
        '--- (1) Lookup Account     (2) New Account     (quit) Shutdown ---\n'
        '------------------------------------------------------------------')
        mainmenugo = 'n' #Stop the loop from itirating forever on start
        mainmenuselect = input('Type your selection and press return : ')

        if mainmenuselect == '1':  ## Account Options Mode
            search = input('Enter the contact last name to search : ')
            for row in reader:
                if search == row['ContactLast']:
                    print (row['Company'], 'has a balance of $', row['Credit'], '. What would you like to do?')
```

Part of the code was omitted for clarity, but that is why I have it setup as it is, though I am sure there are simpler ways of going about it. I have tried a few different things but am really not sure where to begin as I am getting very few errors with this one but no output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are experiencing the following problem. [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) in Python 3 would *evaluate the user input* effectively converting a user input 1 to an integer `1` which then you are trying to compare with a string `'1'`.

In other words, here is what is happening:

```
In [1]: search = input('Enter the contact last name to search : ')
Enter the contact last name to search : 1

In [2]: type(search)
Out[2]: int

In [3]: search == '1'
Out[3]: False
```

In your case, if the user types `1`, the `if mainmenuselect == '1':` comparison would be falsy.